# Journal Software That Works

Tags: software-recommendation, notes

I am working on a book and two computer programs. The amount of time I spend dealing with how everything is organized makes the amount of time I spend writing negligible. My Requirements:

- Hierarchical organization.
- Needs export to document, pdf, or preferably html.
- Rich text editing with support for tables and inserting images.
- Installing from terminal or deb file only.

The following would be a real plus:

- Support for free hand drawing/writing.
- Files in a format that can be read in other programs (xml, txt, html, etc.)
- Notes can open in separate windows.

Answer (score 2):

KDE's journal program in KOrganizer is a likely candidate that provides functionality for all the features you listed. To demonstrate the specific ways in which it accomplishes what you seek:

**Hierarchical organization -**

Create new categories and subcategories for events.
[image]

**Export events to html or print to pdf -** 
[image]

You can be selective with the information output.

[image]

**Rich Text Editing support -**
Check. However, tables and images are something that is not supported.

[image]

**Installing with `apt` -**

This is the only downside: I am not sure how to install it. You will probably have to install KOrganizer, which depends on the KDE Calendar suite and all the KDE core libs.

**Notes opening in separate windows -**

[image: What horrible monitor resolution! Blech!]